# How do I delete / remove icons in Windows 8.1 for programs already uninstalled?

Tags: windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1, when you click on the Start Menu, there is a down arrow to see the complete set of program icons, instead of just the ones pinned on the Start Menu. I found some for an old application I had already uninstalled that did not clean up after itself. The right-click uninstall context menu option only opened the Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features selection, which no longer had the app in question.

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that if I chose the right-click, Open file location on the icon, it brought me to the place where shortcut icons are kept.

On my installation of Windows 8.1, it was in

> C:\Users*MYUSERLOGINID*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

folder, where *MYUSERLOGINID* is my actual user login ID.

After I deleted the folders with the old program names, the icons were gone.